# How to sort std :: MAP for the second parameter when the two template parameters?

Tags: c++11, dictionary, compare

How?I found a lot of examples, but the example with template of the parameter could not be found. I somehow did not work comparator.

```
std::map<K, CacheEntry<T>*, Comparator<K, CacheEntry<T>>> timeMap_;

template<typename T1, typename T2>
        struct Comparator
        {
            typedef std::pair<T1, T2> type;
            bool operator()(const type& l, const type& r) const
            {
                auto nowTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                auto timeL = nowTime - l.second->creationTime();
                auto timeR = nowTime - r.second->creationTime();
                return (std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(timeL).count() > std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(timeR).count());
            }
        };
```

Error:

> Error 1   error C2664: 'bool
>   diadoc::cache::Comparator
>   *>::operator ()(const std::pair &,const std::pair &) const' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::wstring' to 'const
>   std::pair &'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   12.0\vc\include\xutility  521 1   DiadocClient

I try use:

```
template<typename T1, class T2>
```

But it's too not working.
Sort by the second parameter **map**.

Comment: What's `K` in your example? Anyway, the comparator object passed to `std::map` must accept two objects of type `K` as arguments. Can't you just switch the template arguments to `map`?

Comment: @Angew K - is the key, but I do not want to sort by key. I need to sort the field creationTime_ class CacheEntry. That is, I want to sort on the second field.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `std::map` sorts by key, and uses the fact that its contents is sorted to provide logarithmic-time uniqueness checks and access. Can you specify your requirements clearly: What are your uniqueness criteria, sorting criteria, access/modification time complexity criteria? It might turn out you need a more complex container such as [`boost::multi_index`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: There is a unique key that we find an object that stores the time and value. The bottom line is that when I want to delete the oldest member, I appeal to him map.begin (). This container does not suit me?

Comment: Please try to formulate the requirements a bit more clearly and add them to the question; it will improve it greatly (actually make it answerable on its own, that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it seems you need a container which will:

- Store objects which contain `K` and `CacheEntry<T>`
- Not allow two objects with the same value of `K`
- Sort the objects based on `CacheEntry<T>`

There is no standard container which supports this directly. You could use [`boost::multi_index_container`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html), like this:

```
typedef std::pair<K, CacheEntry<T>*> DataItem;


MyTimeType getTime(const DataItem &item)
{
  return getTimeSomehowFrom(item);
}


typedef multi_index_container<
  DataItem,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<global_fun<DataItem, MyTimeType, &getTime>>,
    hashed_unique<member<DataItem, K, &DataItem::first>>
  >
> MyContainer;
```

(The code assumes all relevant `#include`s and `using namespace` directives for brevity).

The above code is not in copy&paste&use shape, but it should be a pointer to get you started. You can read up on the multi-index container and build on the above idea to suit your needs (such as adding tags for indices).

The order of indices (ordered, then unique) matters - for convenienec, the container itself inherits the interface of the first index. In the above case, this would allow you to treat it like a collection of `DataItem`s ordered by the results of `getTime()`, while not allowing duplicate values of `K`.

---

As a side note, notice that you don't need to drag `now()` into your comparator. If `(now - t1) < (now - t2)`, then simply `t2 > t1`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but `std::map` compares keys only(that is the type `K` in you sample code).

You defined a comparator that compares a pair, which is not what `std::map` needed, hence the error.

If your map may contain multiple entries with same key, you should use `multimap` instead.

Comment: Key - is unique in my std::map. I need a map to be sorted by the second field, that is CacheEntry.creationTime_. It's impossible?